# Getting the total of completed in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to calculate the amount of completed activites in a game. So for example I have, "Tennis", "Cricket" and "Golf" as my games and in each of these games there are activities and groups.

So for example I would have `Tennis = 5`

Here is the data structure.

```
"Tennis": {
    "group":{
        "Group 1": {
            "name": "Group name 1",
            "activities": {
                "activity 1": {
                    "completed" : 1
                },
                "activity 2": {
                    "completed" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "Group 2": {
            "name": "Group name 2",
            "activities": {
                "activity 1": {
                    "completed" : 1
                },
                "activity 2": {
                    "completed" : 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

"Cricket": {
    "group":{
        "Group 1": {
            "name": "Group name 1",
            "activities": {
                "activity 1": {
                    "completed" : 1
                },
                "activity 2": {
                    "completed" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "Group 2": {
            "name": "Group name 2",
            "activities": {
                "activity 1": {
                    "completed" : 1
                },
                "activity 2": {
                    "completed" : 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

"Golf": {
    "group":{
        "Group 1": {
            "name": "Group name 1",
            "activities": {
                "activity 1": {
                    "completed" : 1
                },
                "activity 2": {
                    "completed" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "Group 2": {
            "name": "Group name 2",
            "activities": {
                "activity 1": {
                    "completed" : 1
                },
                "activity 2": {
                    "completed" : 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code

```
$result = [];

foreach($games->getGroups as $key => $group)
{
    foreach($group->getActivites as $code => $activity)
    {
        $result[$code] = $activity->getComplete();
    }
}

return $result;
```

and in my Activity.php

```
public function getComplete(): float
{
    return $this->complete;
}
```

I'm struggling as to how I can go about doing this. I'm also using laravel.

Comment: show code that you have right now

Comment: @chojnicki - Sorry about that. I've updated my question.

Comment: Can you show us what's in `$result` after you ran the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Laravel [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map) + [sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sum)

```
collect($games)->map(function($game){
    return collect($game['groups'])->map(function($group){
        return collect($group['activities'])->map(function($activity){
            return $activity['completed'];
        })->sum(); // sum of all the activities
    })->sum(); // sum of all the groups in a game -- this is what you are looking for
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter method using a [higher order proxy/message](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#higher-order-messages) on each group’s activities, resulting in one less nested callable:

```php
collect($games)->map(function ($item) {
  return collect($item->group)->map->activities->sum(function ($item) {
    return collect($item)->sum('completed');
  });
})->toArray();
```